# bash testing for "open terminal"

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I noticed in BASH's list of CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS a `-t` expression that tests whether a file descriptor is an open terminal. i tried the following:

```
if [[ -t $(tty) ]]; then
  echo open terminal $(tty)
else
  echo not open terminal $(tty)
fi;
```

and get my response

```
not open terminal /dev/pts/35
```

i've tried the same from a console and get

```
not open terminal /dev/tty1
```

in the man page `-t`  describes its argument as `FD` a "file descriptor" rather than other conditional expressions which describe the argument as `FILE`

can anyone provide a successful BASH test for a 'file descriptor' which is "open" and "refers to terminal"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File descriptors are small integers.

In particular, `stdin` is fd 0; `stdout` is fd 1; and `stderr` is fd 2.

You will have seen the same use of "file descriptor" in lines like:

```
./cmd 2>&1
```

Which means "run `./cmd`, redirecting fd 2 (stderr) to fd 1 (stdout).

The normal use of `-t` is to tell if input is coming from a terminal:

```
[[ -t 0 ]] && echo "Input is coming from a terminal"
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction. with the your tip i started exploring /dev/fd (which is a symlink to /proc/self/fd). And then with http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three/ I was able to create arbitrary file descriptors and make them persistent across commands (using 'exec 6>~/filename' or 'exec 7>/dev/pts/1'). Using these I was able to determine that '-t' does test positively for any arbitrary fd pointed to any arbitrary terminal. so 'exec 13>/dev/tty3; [[ -t 13 ]] && echo "open term"' gave me the output of "open term" :)